# Using X-Editable - Backend part

Tags: ajax, x-editable

So I'm just trying to use xeditable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#gettingstarted) to make changes to my database via AJAX. 
Since I'm new to this concept and I'm (forcefully) working with PHP for the first time, I need some help.

I setup the frontend part, and a script called (say) script.php is handling the data for me (I need to write the new value in my database).

I can't really understand what to do in the script. Can someone guide me towards it? The docs above don't really do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in a project I worked on a few months back (sorry about the mysql_ stuff – not my choice!)

Something like:

```
<?
include your/database/connection_stuff.php;


// Can't remember if x-editable passes the table in as well or not
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['table']);
// If not, 
$table = 'name_of_table';


$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pk']);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET `$name` = '$value' WHERE id = '$pk'");

?>
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Simple enough. But I've a doubt about $pk. So in my frontend, I need to set pk as the primary key value of the corresponding row in my table? The docs say `pk - primary key of record to be updated (ID in db)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. In my case our tables have a primary key called `id` - you can see that's hard coded in my query. The frontend needs to know about that to know which record to use.

Comment: @RichBradshaw I'm also using x-editable sir. Can you tel me what does the `$name` gives you in your code?